# Resizing image while printing html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to print a `div` of a html page which has texts and images. To do that I used a javascript `function` with `window.print()`. Upto now it prints that `div` with large images.

I need to resize the images keeping proportion.

As I am not from this (`html,css,javascript`) field, I have no idea how to do. 
I searched on internet but didn't get any link with help in resizing image while printing.

Can you give any sort of idea?

Comment: Can you put an example of your HTML please?

Comment: Why don't you  use mediaqueries? `@media print { ... }`

Comment: you should try '@media print' and specify height and width

Comment: @DarkBee, can you give it as answer with some details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control the layout of the print document by using mediaqueries. An example would be

```
@media print { 
    img {
         max-width : 300px;
         height : auto;
    }
}
```

more information about this and some examples can be found [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
for(var i = 0; i<images.length; i++) {
  if (images[i].width > screen.width) {
    // Reduce the width so image fits.
    var factor = (screen.width-50)/img.width;
    images[i].width *= factor;
    images[i].height *= factor;
  }
 if (images[i].height > screen.height) {
   // Reduce the height so it fits.
   var factor = (screen.height-50)/images[i].height;
   images[i].width *= factor;
   images[i].height *= factor;
  }

}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for answering. But this is for one image. 
I have multiple images.
Actually the images are added to the page by a loop in php file.

Comment: This is just sample code. You can get your images as an array from your HTML using `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` and then iterate over the array. I'll update my answer

Comment: I will check and inform you here.

Answer (score 0):

you can just set the image's `width()` and `height()` like below:

```
$('.imgClass').width(700); // Units are assumed to be pixels
$('.imgClass').height(700);
//.imgClass is a common class on multiple images
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use inline css for defining the dimensions of the image

```
<img style="width:150px;float: right" src="image_path.png">
```